# What's behind this implicit cast in Scala?

Tags: scala, casting

I'm not familiar with Scala and come across this problem below when using interactive mode:

```
scala>"abc"+4
res0: java.lang.String = abc4
scala>4+"abc"
res1: String = 4abc
```

What I'm curious about is that how the type of the result can be different(`java.lang.String` vs `String`). And in Book *Seven Languages in Seven Weeks* the two types are both `java.lang.String`.

BTW,the version of scala interpreter is 2.9.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the JVM, scala's `String` is just an alias to `java.lang.String`. The fact that the Repl sometimes displays the type as `String` and sometimes as  `java.lang.String` is just a minor (REPL specific) glitch that does not affect in any way the runtime behaviour.

For what it's worth, here is what I get in scala 2.10-RC1:

```
scala> "abc"+4
res0: String = abc4

scala> 4+"abc"
res1: String = 4abc
```

Comment: What, the type alias? Scala could have defined its very own String class but there would only be downsides to it (in terms of performance by example as you'd need many conversions when calling Java APIs). And directly using java.lang.String would mean introducing a dependency to Java right into the language (as opposed to a dependency at the implementation level).

Comment: I suppose that the output of the type should be consistent so that they would always be `String` in this case, although the implementation of `String` may actually be the alias of the corresponding __String__ type either in JVM or CLR environment.

Comment: Sure, and as shown in my post this is actually the case in scala 2.10

Answer (score 0):

What do you want ???

```
scala> (4+"abc").getClass.getName
res3: java.lang.String = java.lang.String

scala> ("abc"+4).getClass.getName
res5: java.lang.String = java.lang.String
```

Both are java.lang.String.
I think the Interactive Interpreter just says `String` not `java.lang.String`.
But we have java.lang.String instances.

`("abc"+4): '+' is applied to java.lang.String, and returns java.lang.String. This is true both on Java and Scala.`

`(4+"abc") on Java: '+' is applied to java.lang.Integer, and returns java.lang.String.`

`(4+"abc") on Scala: '+' is applied to scala.Int, and returns String. '+(x: String)' is defined on scala.Int.`

At the output of the Interactive Interpreter, `type String = java.lanag.String` is applied, which is defined on Predef.scala. The reverse is not defined, of course.

> This looks so dirty

I don't think so.

> should be consistent so that they would always be String

I don't think so. It is consistent.

java version "1.7.0_09"

Scala code runner version 2.9.2

Comment: What I mean for `consistent` is that the output of the type should not tell me whether it is a `String` based on JVM or CLR.According to @ Régis Jean-Gilles, this problem seems to have been solved with *scala 2.10-RC1*.